# Call a function in the parent View from the inline Callout (acting as confirmation Alert)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex4.6, flex-mobile

I'm trying to add [an inline Callout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS7dd5c1363434bb706aafb086131b54b6ec7-8000.html#WSf32eaeda604069473c9c12bb131ddea1166-8000) to my networked flex mobile app which would ask the user - if she is really sure, that she wants to leave a chat room.

However I get the compiler error - because the (non-static) function `fetch(MyEvent.LEAVE)` below belongs to the parent View.

Is there still a way to call it (maybe through an `outerDocument`, `parent`, `owner` or smth. similar)?

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Component className="ConfirmLeave">
        <s:Callout 
            horizontalPosition="middle"
            verticalPosition="middle">
            <s:VGroup>
                <s:Label text="Are you sure?" />
                <s:HGroup>
                    <s:Button id="_leaveYes"
                              label="Yes"
                              click="fetch(MyEvent.LEAVE)" />
                    <s:Button id="_leaveNo"
                              label="No"
                              click="close()" />
                </s:HGroup>
            </s:VGroup>
        </s:Callout>        
    </fx:Component>
</fx:Declarations>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself with a listener for [PopUpEvent.CLOSE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/events/PopUpEvent.html) event:

```
private var _confirmLeave:ConfirmLeave = new ConfirmLeave();

_confirmLeave.addEventListener(PopUpEvent.CLOSE, handleLeaveCallback);

_confirmLeave.open(this, true);

        private function handleLeaveCallback(event:PopUpEvent):void {
            if (!event.commit)
                return;

            fetch(MyEvent.LEAVE);
        }
```